Are soldiers at war generally permitted to vote in national elections?
This might initially sound like an absurd question due to nations like Ukraine's law automatically extending presidential and prime ministerial terms until any war has concluded, if martial law is enacted.
However, in the case of Russia's Special Military Operation (SMO), conscripts and volunteer non-commissioned officers and commissioned officers alike were at war in and outside of Russian territory during a national election. According to War-time electoral pact (Wikipedia), this should also apply to the United Kingdom during the 1st and 2nd world wars.
I can imagine that the logistics stress would be problematic. Consequently, in nations which hold elections during wartime, are combat personnel generally permitted to vote? If so, how, and why?

Russia does not like to call their war a war, so this is a special situation. But the soldiers are usually not the problem, they can be sent absentee ballots at their unit. The displaced civilians are much harder to track.

The UK had by-elections (what the US would call special elections) during the world wars, but in both national elections were delayed by hostilities. The electoral pacts were essentially a gentleman’s agreements for seats not to change hands, thus meaning it didn’t matter whether anyone voted in them. More generally, war and martial law/ a state of emergency aren’t the same thing.

There's 2 separate questions. Members of the armed forces serving overseas are generally allowed to vote - if you type a few words in to Google rather than Stack Exchange, you can easily find the procedures for UK, US, and other countries (obviously postal voting plays a major role - most militaries have postal services for serving troops). But elections can be delayed in wartime, as others have mentioned. If you're interested in a specific country or group of countries you should ask specifically, rather than get a lengthy answer about a nation you have no interest in.

@StuartF, those differing results for different nations were actually why I asked. I'm trying to ascertain whether it's standard procedure amongst militaries to permit soldiers to vote in times of conflict, and whether the conflict being a foreign insurgency (like the USA in Afghanistan) or a peer-nation war (like Germany and the UK in WW2) differ. That last point is my primary area of confusion - why are some conflicts treated differently to others, and how does one determine that? Russia's is especially strange - it's both at war and not at war. Perhaps my question need rephrasal?

Why would you imagine that wartime would affect this? It might make the logistics difficult, but not legality of voting.

There is no general rule. It is decided on a case by case basis.

@Barmar, because I can't see how troops engaged in combat would be able to send ballots - getting logistics personnel to an encircled FOB wouldn't be worth the danger, considering that a few soldiers' votes probably shan't change a national election's outcome.

@RokeJulianLockhart During the Korean and Viet Nam wars, there was mail between soldiers and their families. Surely the same could be used for mail-in ballots.

@Barmar, thanks. That makes sense.

Unless stated otherwise soldiers are citizens and if citizens are allowed to vote (not a given there, are dictatorships or segregated societies where that might not be the case), then in a democracy soldiers are consequently also allowed to vote.
Now obviously being at war creates a lot of problems doing so, many of which are more pragmatic than ideological. So it's not that there is a law that mandates that people on a special military operation are allowed to vote, but soldiers in a war aren't. It's probably more of a problem of:

Is your country in ruins?
Are there areas under occupation? Like how would Ukrainians in Crimea vote?
Is your country an active battle ground?
Are there whole areas which are not safe to enter or leave?
Is it safe for people to gather at one location?
Is the postal infrastructure still intact to do voting by mail?
Do you know where people live and whether they are still alive?
Like you'd need to notify people of an upcoming election
Do you have the resources to organize an election?
Could you afford a new government making major changes?
Is your government still in command anyway?
Or did the military already seize control due to real or pretextual urgency

So for obvious reasons when a country does a spec ops operation (limited operation by highly trained soldiers, not a war you don't want to call that way), then the rest of the country is largely untouched by that, meaning you still have plenty of people and infrastructure to facilitate that. Soldiers could vote before their employment, if that is close to the election or they could vote by mail or they could have a voting booth at a fortified HQ.
Now whether the soldier vote is significant in swinging an election (likely not), whether it's free and fair without the ability to independently inform yourself (though that's hard for anybody in a country at war), whether soldiers are loyal to their government or think it sucks because they basically by definition have too little to survive. Or whether that is more or less symbolic to create a sense of normality within chaos, that's a whole different issue. But if possible countries would probably do it and if just for the last part, to pretend you're in control and boost the morale. Like the sentiment of "I'm expected to give my life for this country, but am not allowed to vote" usually isn't great. While simply not being able to facilitate that is something that is much easier to sell to people seeing how shitty the situation is anyway.
Though yeah often enough in war time there's a real or pretextual supremacy of the TINA-principle (there is no alternative). So it's not really the ideologies of the parties shaping politics, but the necessities of war, so they often agree to postpone elections and whatnot till after the war or descend into military dictatorships without consent.
